# ssh_dispatch_run_fatal when trying to ssh repos to gitlab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I'm trying to access repositories from the official gitlab server. Now, I'm getting the error

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 104.210.2.228: no matching cipher found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

if I try to pull, clone, or even `ssh git@gitlab.com`.

I created a new key and tested to check if the key was the problem but the same error persists.

Some info of my system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:    wily

$ git --version
git version 2.5.0

$ ssh -vvvT git@gitlab.com
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reuserg configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [104.210.2.228] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 104.210.2.228: no matching cipher found
```

It seems that I have some error or difference with the versions of OpenSSH, but I'm not sure. Any pointers to what is going on, and how to fix it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no matching cipher found

means that your sever and client offers different ciphers.

Client side:

```
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc,arcfour
```

Server side:

```
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

The client side proposal are certainly not default values, because they are unsafe ciphers (disabled on any sane server). You should check your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and remove the line

```
Ciphers blowfish-cbc,arcfour
```

or similar (regardless how and why it get there). If you need legacy ciphers to connect to legacy systems, there is always match block, which you can use

```
Match legacy.hostmane
  Ciphers blowfish-cbc,arcfour
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar issue like this while trying to connect with remote in git lab after upgrading my Macbook to HighSierra.

> Unable to negotiate with xx.xx.xx.xx port xx: no matching cipher
>   found. Their offer: aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc fatal: Could not read from
>   remote repository.

To solve this issue, just edit the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file to add the ciphers that support server configuration.

This can be simply done by uncommenting the line `# Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc` by removing the # charactor in front.

As the ssh folder has access restrictions, use vim editor or make a copy of the file in somewhere like desktop and make changes and then replace at the /etc/ssh/ folder.

Comment: Then you had a completely different (opposite) issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your client ssh to use one of the allowed ciphers on the server. One way to do it is to modify ~/.ssh/config with this:

```
Host gitlab.com
     Ciphers aes256-ctc
```